# A iOS-App should check FTP-Server when the app is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

At the moment my users have to push the button in the app to get there new dates and adresses for there meetings.

The app open a ftp-connection and there the app checks if new csv-files existing. If there is a file available it would download it and import the data.

So my opinion is, that the app do this also when it is in the background or like the default mail-app. also when it is not open.

Did anyone have a little tip for me, where i have to search?

Comment: Try it with the new background fetch in ios 7 or with content-available PN

Answer (score 1):

try this tut from ray wenderlich. for in depth tut you should get a copy if his pdf book for iOS 7:

[NSURLSession Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial)

by the way. it is possible to sent notification from server when new data arrives? that would be a more elegant way as to check via ftp